# Diagrams in path integral approach to quantum mechanics

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, graphs

I am working with overleaf; I need to draw some diagrams as an introduction to path integral approach. I attach an image, kindly check it and help me. [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. I did not vote less on your question, nor did I vote more. Please ask only one question at a time, not three. For each question, give the mathematical functions you wish to construct. It is best if you have some code in your question.

Comment: ok Will do@AndreC

Comment: Since you have an answer for the first graphic, delete the other two questions.

Comment: I edited the question@ AndréC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is a nice one to do with random path angles in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so to compile it in Overleaf, you will need to pick the `lualatex` option in the menu.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path xx, tt;
    xx = (left -- 5 right) scaled 64;
    tt = xx rotated 90;

    drawarrow xx; label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    drawarrow tt; label.top("$t$", point 1 of tt);

    z0 = (42, 18);
    z1 = (264, 300);

    vardef random_path(expr a, b, r) = 
        a {dir (r + uniformdeviate (180 - 2r))} .. 
        b {dir (r + uniformdeviate (180 - 2r))} enddef;

    for i=1 upto 10:
        draw random_path(z0, z1, 18) withpen pencircle scaled 1/2 withcolor 2/3 blue;
    endfor

    dotlabel.bot("$(x', t')$", z0);
    dotlabel.top("$(x'', t'')$", z1);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It gives an error as "file lualatex.sty not found"@Thruston

Comment: On Overleaf?  Did you change the compiler setting to `LuaLaTeX` as I suggested?

Comment: yes, I got it, thanks, does the use of that compiler make any problems  in future as my project proceeds@ Thruston

Comment: I don't need the bottom part of t axis, how to remove it?@ Thruston

Comment: your answer is helpful, but I need some more spread in the x-axis, your graph does not as I required,for that what I need to do?@ Thruston

Comment: Follow the link at the top of my answer for tutorials and manuals for Metapost; they will help you make changes to the diagram

Comment: Is there a way to make this code executable also for ```pdflatex```?

Comment: @ric.san - no but you could compile it with `lualatex` to a stand alone PDF file and then include that in a `pdflatex` document with `\includegraphics`.