# How do I draw Feynman paths in Overleaf?

Tags: graphics, diagrams, graphs

I am preparing my thesis, and I need to add a file from Feynman path integral approach, as shown in the following figure, to my project. I am working with overleaf, and I have no idea on how to do it, please help me.
[image]

Comment: All your question are a request of a code.

Comment: Have a serious look at `tikz` and `pgfplots`, this shoudl solve most of your questions

Comment: This is really very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555285/15036).  Why don't you try to adapt that answer to this problem, then ask here when you get stuck?

Comment: GeoGebra can be a good start to have some TikZ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not going to draw the whole thing for you. I am giving you a good starting point, though. What I did here is beginners stuff, there are many more elegant (and shorter) ways to draw this.

If you get stuck, there is an excellent manual: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

You should be able to draw this within a couple of hours:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [color=gray!30]  [step=1cm] (0,-4) grid (10,4); 
    \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[below] {$t$};
    \draw[<->,thick] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] {$x$};
    \draw [color=red] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1.5) (2,-1.5) (3,0.5) (4,0) (4.25,-0.5)};
    \draw [color=black](0,0) node[left]{$(x,t)$};
    \fill[red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (1,1.5) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (2,-1.5) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (3,0.5) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (4,0) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (4.5,-1) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (5,-1) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (5.5,-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz plot]

Comment: Excellent but maybe a little threatening with its 1302 pages... ;-) :-)

Comment: Thanks, I Got It@phil-elkabat